# C++ code don't have errors but not giving output

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, for-loop, output

I am writing code for selection sort in c++. It gives no error when i compile it with the command `g++ main.cpp -o main` in powershell but when i run the code with `./main`, it don't show anything. I tried with hello world program and it worked. I don't know why the selection sort code not working.

Here Is the code of Selection sort

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n, a[n];

   cout << "Enter the size of the array = ";
   cin >> n;

   cout << "Enter the numbers :" << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       cin >> a[i];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
   {
       for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
       {
           if (a[i] > a[j])
           {
               int temp = a[i];
               a[i] = a[j];
               a[j] = temp;
           }
       }
   }

   for (int b=0; b<n; b++)
   {
       cout<<a[b];
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: turn on warnings to see the *errors*: https://godbolt.org/z/ErPY3x936

Comment: Even if n would have been initialized, which it is not. a[n] is not valid C++. Have a look at std::vector if you want a dynamically (re)sizeable array. ALWAYS initialize your variables in C++, the compiler won't implicitly do it for you.

Comment: *It gives no error when i compile it* -- That only means there are no syntax errors.  If I asked you to write a program to add two numbers, but instead it subtracted two numbers, that program will also "compile with no errors".  But is it correct?  No.  The program is not *logically* correct.

Comment: *I don't know why the selection sort code not working.* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: Fyi, that isn't a classic [selection sort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/selection_sort_algorithm.htm). Selection sort scans the unsorted portion of the sequence, remembering where the current extreme value is indexed along the way. once the scan is complete the index location where the most extreme value resides is swapped with with the proper location (the iteration count of the outer loop used as an index). In short, there should only be *one* swap per outer-loop iteration, and it should happen *after* the inner loop is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **2 problems** in your program.

##### Mistake 1

In Standard C++ the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So take for example,

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n] ; //INCORRECT because n is not a constant expression
```

The correct way to write the above would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //CORRECT
```

##### Mistake 2

You're using an **uninitialized variable** which leads to **undefined behavior**. In particular when you wrote:

```
int n, a[n]; //here variable n is uninitialized and holds **indeterminate value**.
```

In the above statement, you are creating an `int` named `n` but since you have not explicitly initialized it, it holds an **indeterminate value**.

Next, you're using that garbage value  as the size of the array `a`. But note that using uninitialized variable results in **undefined behavior**.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

This is why it is advised that

> always initialize built in types in local/block scope.

##### Solution

A better way would be to use `std::vector` as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int n = 0; //always initialize built in types in local/block scope 
    
    std::cout<<"Enter size: "<<std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    //create a vector of size n  
    std::vector<int> a(n);
    
    //iterate and ask for input 
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<"Enter element: "<<std::endl;
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; ++i) 
    {
        
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.size(); j++) {
          
          if (a[j] < a[index])
            index = j;
        }
        
        int temp = a[index];
        a[index] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
        
    }
    std::cout<<"The elements of the vector are:"<<std::endl;
    //print the element of the vector 
    for(const int& elem: a)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/3tf6tyTv9).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Always initialize variables. A declaration without initialization is a code smell, eg this one:

```
int n;
```

The issue immediately follows, because

```
int n, a[n];
```

uses `n` uninitialized. Compilers do a pretty good job at warning about this: https://godbolt.org/z/ErPY3x936. Before you initialize `n`, it has an indeterminate value. Using its value leads to undefined behavior. Further, `a[n]` is a variable length array (unless `n` is a constant expression), which is not part of standard C++. When you need an array whose size is only known at runtime, you can use a `std::vector`:

```
int n = 0;
cout << "Enter the size of the array = ";
cin >> n;
std::vector<int> arr(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a variable length array

```
int n, a[n];
```

Variable length arrays is nit a standard C++ feature. So you should avoid to use them. Instead use the standard container `std::vector<int>`.

Moreover the variable `n` is not initialized. So the declaration of the variable length array invokes undefined behavior.

Within the for loops where you are sorting the array there are too many swaps of elements of the array.

The selection sort algorithm assumes that a selected element in an array is swapped at most one time.

And there is the standard function `std::swap` that can be used instead of manually swapping elements.

Your program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of the array (0 - exit): ";
    std::cin >> n;

    if ( n )
    {
        std::vector<int> v( n );

        std::cout << "Enter the numbers :" << std::endl;

        for ( auto &item : v )
        {
            std::cin >> item;
        }

        for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
        {
            auto min = i;

            for ( auto j = i + 1; j < v.size(); j++ )
            {
                if (  v[j] < v[min] ) min = j;
            }

            if ( min != i ) std::swap( v[min], v[i] ); 
        }

       for ( const auto &item : v )
       {
           std::cout << item << ' ';
       }
       std::cout << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}.
```